# How can I normalize a table by extracting comma separated text from a column into a child table?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that contains definitions with a space and comma separator. The definitions looks like this "cat, dog,horse ,house,city". There are spaces that can appear before or after the comma.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WordForm] 
(
    [WordFormId]       VARCHAR (20)  NOT NULL,
    [WordFormIdentity] INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [WordId]           VARCHAR (20)  NOT NULL,
    [Definition]       VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([WordFormId] ASC),

    CONSTRAINT [FK_WordFormPos] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([PosId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Pos] ([PosId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_WordFormWord] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([WordId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Word] ([WordId])
);
```

I would like to remove the Definition column and replace it with a table with one definition for each row:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Definition]
(
    [DefinitionId] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [WordFormId] VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
    [Text] VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([SynonymId] ASC),

    CONSTRAINT [FK_DefinitionWordForm] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([WordFormId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[WordForm] ([WordFormId])
);
```

Can someone suggest how I can take the data out of `Definition` column and insert it into the text column of the rows in the new `Definition` table? Hoping for a solution that will also check `Definition` is not null.

Thank you.

Comment: Just use a string splitting function to split it from comma, trim the data and filter out the nulls. Is there a specific part you're having trouble with?

Comment: [Aaron Bertrand to the rescue!](http://sqlperformance.com/2016/03/sql-server-2016/string-split)

Comment: Good decision to normalize!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following query to split the comma delimited list and get a row for each definition value in the list.

```
Select [WordFormId]
     ,RTRIM(LTRIM([Definition])) [Definition]
from 
(
SELECT t.[WordFormId] 
          ,Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') [Definition]
FROM   
    (SELECT [WordFormId]
            ,Cast ('<X>' + Replace([Definition], ',', '</X><X>') + '</X>' AS XML) AS Data
     FROM    [dbo].[WordForm]
    ) AS t CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/X') AS Split(a)
 )a
```

I have also used `LTRIM()` and `RTRIM()` functions to get rid of any white spaces.

Comment: Thanks.  Can you add a line to also show how I could insert this data into the Definition table also.